# What is the difference between partial tag helper and HTML helper in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

What is the difference between `partial` tag helper implemented in .net core 2.1:

```
<partial name="_AuthorPartial" />
```

and

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_AuthorPartial")
```

Which one should I use in the production and what are the benefits?

Comment: There isn't a great deal of difference here. Tag Helpers are the *new thing* in ASP.NET Core but Html Helpers still exist mostly for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Those pieces of code are equivalent. My suggestion is to be consisent and either use one or the other,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn't a difference when it comes to how the server handles them.  The end result is exactly the same from a server perspective.

There are some benefits (from a developer's perspective) listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that are worth noting, [specifically the improved Intellisense that they provide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers).

In my experience, Tag Helpers are also easier for UI designers to read and use as they look and feel more like HTML than Html Helpers.